# mysql query confusion using in and natural join quantity

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm confused with MySQL query.

Let say we have

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    pid VARCHAR( 50 ) PRIMARY KEY,
    passwd CHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL,
    fname VARCHAR( 50 ), 
    lname VARCHAR( 50 ),
    d_privacy INT NOT NULL  -- change from part 1 spec, which said varchar
);

CREATE TABLE event (
     eid  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
     start_time  TIME NOT NULL,
     duration    TIME NOT NULL,
     description VARCHAR(50),
     pid         VARCHAR(50),
     FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES person(pid)
);


CREATE TABLE invited (  
   pid  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   eid  INT NOT NULL,
   response INT,
   visibility INT,
   PRIMARY KEY (pid, eid),
   FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES person(pid),
   FOREIGN KEY (eid) REFERENCES event(eid)
);

CREATE TABLE friend_of (
   sharer VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   viewer VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   level INT,
   PRIMARY KEY (sharer, viewer),
   FOREIGN KEY (sharer) REFERENCES person(pid),
   FOREIGN KEY (viewer) REFERENCES person(pid)
);
```

For example say I'm a viewer = 'AA'
and want to see viewer's all sharer's schedule (`eid` and `description`) 
I tried it with in and natural join quantity but code looks ugly...

```
select *
from invited natural join person
where person.pid in

(

select pid

from invited 
where pid in(

SELECT sharer
from friend_of
natural join invited
where friend_of.viewer = 'AA'
and friend_of.sharer =  invited.pid

    ))
```

This code is not done yet. I have to natural join with event and 
put the description quantity. but I stuck here

if you have a better way to write this functionality please.

Comment: What's your question? Instead of using `IN`, you should join with the other tables.

Comment: event's PID is the creater of the pid. this give me a problem with join with other tables. other PID is the some one who invited to the party

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NATURAL JOIN` joins tables wherever there are identically named columns.  So, for example, one *could* naturally join `invited` to `person` or `event`, since the columns `pid` and `eid` respectively exist across the tables.

Note however that it's generally best to avoid `NATURAL JOIN` and instead explicitly name the columns on which you wish to join with `USING` or `ON`, as it avoids accidentally joining on unrelated columns that happen to be named alike (especially if one's schema changes in the future).

When joining `friend_of` to `invited`, there aren't any like-named columns and so `NATURAL JOIN` will effectively perform a `CROSS JOIN`.  Therefore, one can instead do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM   person
  JOIN invited   USING (pid)
  JOIN event     USING (pid, eid)
  JOIN friend_of   ON  friend_of.sharer = invited.pid
WHERE  friend_of.viewer = 'AA'
```

Comment: Hey eggtal, your code seems correct but when I tried it with this code  it return the empty value, I check it with my hand and it suppose to be return some value. strange

Comment: @Kingkong: Impossible to say what's the matter without seeing your data.  Perhaps post a sample on http://sqlfiddle.com?